# Difference between conversions in google analytics and actual conversion

Tags: google-analytics, data-conversion

So this is what is happening.

I am using a schedule form, from ScheduleOnce for call scheduling. This acts just as any schedule form and I am going with the assumption (which is probably correct) that the mistake is not with the scheduling software.

I am running an AdWords campaign and I am tracking call schedules as a conversion in AdWords.

I have been marking conversion in both AdWords and Analytics but I have no scheduled calls in my software.

Can't find the reason behind this. 
Can anyone help?
Where should I be looking at?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your "ScheduleOnce" software, but this question is coming up very often. As I had to explain this also recently, I strongly recommend you to read https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2679221?hl=en which is explaining everything. Some definitions are completely different:

[image: Google Analytics vs. Google Adwords Conversions]

Then of course also other factors can be different: Some people can be blocking via browser-addons Google Analytics or Adwords and in opposite. You will always have differences no matter what you do. For e-commerce stuff, I usually take the metrics of the e-commerce platform and calculate the difference to have at least an approximate real value.